# Yahoo Mail not saving sent mail from My application

Tags: c#, smtp, sendmail

In my application, I am sending mail from my yahoo mail Id using SMTP Server authentication.
When send mail,It Successfully Sent mail and recipients get mail as well.
Problem is yahoo not maintaining Sent mail copies in my yahoo account.
As i know i need to set "Save copy message in Sent folder" checked for saving but it just working with when i send mail from yahoo itself not from others application..

The Same thing is not happening with Gmail as it saves sent Mails from both (Gmail account and My application).

What setting need to do in yahoo or i need to set some Setting in my application?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Whenever I send an email through SMTP (even with Outlook) it doesn't show up in the web interface. It doesn't sound like a C#-specific quesiton though, must be something on their end.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `EmailMessage` if possible.

Refer following code and see if it works-

```
// Create an email message and identify the Exchange service.
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);

// Add properties to the email message.
message.Subject = "Interesting";
message.Body = "The merger is finalized.";
message.ToRecipients.Add("user1@contoso.com");

// Send the email message and save a copy.
message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Reference- [Creating and sending email messages by using the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633628%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Can i send Images in Message Body with this Class?

Comment: You need to check that. See if you can solve your main problem first.